# linq query to get value from XML to a c# class properties - Linq To XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
<Response SessionId="55C10AC0E63B44FCB1868FF4B49E6DF7" xmlns="http://MySample.Sample.com/Sample.xsd">
  <Status Success="true" Message="OK" ErrorCode="0" /> 
  <Data>
  <List Name="My.API.Customer.Customers" Type="My.API.Customer.Customers">
    <Item Key="12345678-0" State="Unchanged">
    <Value Name="MasterCustomerId" Value="12345678" /> 
     <Value Name="SubCustomerId" Value="0" /> 
    <Value Name="IsAbstractAuthor" Value="False" /> 
    <Value Name="LastFirstName" Value="Cal, Duke" /> 
    <Value Name="IsAbstractReviewer" Value="False" /> 
    <Value Name="NamePrefix" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="FirstName" Value="Cal" /> 
    <Value Name="MiddleName" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="LastName" Value="Duke" /> 
    <Value Name="NameSuffix" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="NameCredentials" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="SearchName" Value="DUKE;CAL" /> 
    <Value Name="LabelName" Value="Cal Duke" /> 
    <Value Name="FormalSalutation" Value="Mr. Duke" /> 
    <Value Name="IsCustomerStatusActive" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="OrganizationId" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="OrganizationUnitId" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="RecordType" Value="I" /> 
    <Value Name="CanPlaceOrderFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="CanCreateSegmentsFlag" Value="False" /> 
    <Value Name="BillPrimaryAccountFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="Nickname" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="InformalSalutation" Value="Cal" /> 
    <Value Name="CustomerClassCode" Value="INDIV" /> 
    <Value Name="CustomerStatusCode" Value="ACTIVE" /> 
    <Value Name="CustomerStatusDate" Value="8/9/2010 4:17:23 PM" /> 
    <Value Name="AllowFaxFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="AllowEmailFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="AllowPhoneFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="AllowLabelSalesFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="AllowSolicitationFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="AllowInternalMailFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="SolicitationRemovalDate" Value="12:00:00 AM" /> 
    <Value Name="TaxableFlag" Value="True" /> 
    <Value Name="FederalTaxId" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="VATId" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="TaxExemptId" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="Ssn" Value="" /> 
    <Value Name="GenderCode" Value="M" /> 
    <Value Name="BirthDate" Value="12:00:00 AM" /> 
    <Value Name="EthnicityCode" Value="99" /> 
    <Value Name="AnnualIncomeRangeCode" Value="" /> 
   </Item>
 </List>
    </Data>
</Response>
```

If I have C# class called SampleUser with properties for FirstName,LastName etc., how can I use linq-to-Xml and get the values from the XML to be assigned to the appropriate C# class properties.

Comment: maybe xmlSerializer could handle that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The descendants of Item all having the same ID sort of makes this difficult for Linq-to-XML (from a code-bloating standpoint), but not impossible.

A short example to get you started is this

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://MySample.Sample.com/Sample.xsd";

var sampleUsers = from item in document.Root.Element(ns + "Data").Element(ns + "List").Elements(ns + "Item")
                  select new SampleUser
                  {
                      FirstName = item.Elements(ns + "Value").First(v => v.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("FirstName")).Attribute("Value").Value,
                      LastName = item.Elements(ns + "Value").First(v => v.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("LastName")).Attribute("Value").Value
                  };
```

It would be far better if the XML was like

```
<Item>
  <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Item>
```

Perhaps you can explore a transformation to actually get there.

Comment: That's one complex Linq you have mentioned Anthony. Thanks it works great!

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var a = from b in doc.Descendants("Value")
        select new SampleUser(){FirstName = b.Attribute("firstName").Value,
                                lastName = b.Attribute("lastName").value};
```

Comment: I had a method which returns IEnumerable<SampleUser> and tried your code Vinay It is null for a some reason. I will try it and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to XML isn't the best tool for this purpose.

If you have an XSD schema for the response, you can use the [XSD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) tool that comes with Visual Studio to generate a class for you. It will also generate a `Deserialize` factory method that will allow you to create an instance of the class from XML data.

If you don't have an XSD, you can use a tool that will infer the schema from a sample. Here's an [example](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/) of such an app.